# Binsearch in cell matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary-search, cell-array

I have a cell matrix with 2 rows - sorted cell array of different strings and array of numbers. Also I have an example string. It's guarantied that this string appears in the 1st row in the cell array. I want to get index of example's appearance in cell array of strings.

Is there any function in Matlab, that provides solving with logarithmic complexity (something like binary search)?

Comment: How are the strings ordered?

Comment: @Daniel, alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) code (type `open ismember`), you'll  see that it basically

1. Checks if the array is sorted (by calling [`issorted`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/issorted.html));
2. If not, it sorts the array;
3. Then it applies binary search.

So you can directly use `ismember`.

Example:

```
>> strings = {'a', 'aa', 'be', 'day', 'yes'};
>> [tf, loc ] = ismember('day', strings);
>> loc
loc =
     4
```

Or maybe modify `ismember` (**save it with another name**) to bypass step 1, since you already know your array is sorted.

Comment: how does it checks if array is sorted?

Comment: If you want to bypass the call to `issorted` for your special purposes,  you could modify `ismember`. __Of course, save it with another name__. I've updated my answer